# Change database location of docker couchdb instance?

Tags: database, docker, couchdb, containers, volumes

I have a server with two disks: one is an SSD used by the operating system and the other is a normal 2.5TB HDD.

Now on this server I'm runnning Fedora Server 22 with Docker and there is one image currently running: Fedora/couchdb.

the problem is that this container is saving the database to the much smaller SSD when it should really be stored in the much bigger HDD.

How can I setup this image to store the database on the HDD?

Other Information:
[image: Mount Points]

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the disk and index location for couchdb in the config file with

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /path/to/dir
view_index_dir = /path/to/dir
```

how to add a custom configuration to the startup is explained here

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/intro.html

of course in order to use the desired path for your dbs in the container you need to make sure it is accessible inside the docker image

this explains everything you need to do so:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/

if that does not help please explain in more detail what your setup is and what you want to acchieve.